# WCF Custom Authentication not working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, wcf-security

Trying to implement a simple 'username'/'password' authentication for wcf service. But its just not working. No errors/exceptions.
Here is the web config code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>     
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
        <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
      <service name="XYZService"
               behaviorConfiguration="XYZBehavior">        
        <!-- use base address specified above, provide one endpoint -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="XYZBinding"
                  contract="IXYZService" />
        <!--<endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="XYZBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
        <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior>
                        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                        <serviceCredentials>
                            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="XYZBinding.LicensingServer.CCustomValidatorClass, XYZBinding.LicensingServer"/>
                        </serviceCredentials>
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        </system.serviceModel>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Validate Code:

```
public class CCustomValidatorClass : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if(userName != "Test" || password != "1234567")
            {
                throw new FaultException("The provided credentials are invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
```

There are no errors or exceptions. I am able to call the service and execute without any credentials. On local debugging the validate method is never hit.

I have no idea what is getting missed out.

Comment: I'm no expert in WCF, but the first question in these scenarios is always: "Are you sure that this config is being used?". Check this by changing something in the config that would break the app and if the app still works, it's using another config :-)

Comment: Just updated 'customUserNamePasswordValidatorType' and the wcf test client threw an error. Changed back to original. WCF Test client runs smoothly.

Comment: You're not showing us the important and interesting part in your config - the <services> section. Do you even have a service that actually uses these binding configurations and those security settings?? From what you've posted so far, it doesn't look like that....

Comment: well there are no <services> sections defined. Maybe that's the problem. I'll just add/configure one and update this.

Comment: updated with Service section. Now I am getting 'Security settings for this service require 'Basic' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.' error.

Comment: Have you tried tracing it? (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Is the service hosted in IIS? If so this might not be supported since IIS does the tranport auth. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx